# Population Count specific algorithm explanation/Implementation on Assembly

Tags: algorithm, assembly, mips

I found an algorithm for population count which goes like this:

```
unsigned int v; // count the number of bits set in v
unsigned int c; // c accumulates the total bits set in v
for (c = 0; v; c++)
{
  v &= v - 1; // clear the least significant bit set
}
```

My question is, is it possible to implement this into Assembly (MIPS) ? I don't understand how the "for" loop works, if anyone could explain what the condition is (I suspect it's 0 < v ?). There is another question about this algorithm but it does not explain the algorithm on an instruction-level depth.

[Cast some light on population count algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678685/cast-some-light-on-population-count-algorithm)

Sidenote: My hw is to implement a popcount algorithm which counts the set bits of a 32bit interger on MIPS (a subroutine) but I am not allowed to use multiplication/division by any means. Hope my question is not a duplicate spam :/

Comment: The condition here is "`v` is truthy", or in other words, `v != 0`. (This is, of course, equivalent to `v > 0` for unsigned integers.)

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to make sure I understood this correctly ^^

Comment: "s it possible to implement this into Assembly (MIPS)" ... guess what will happen if you compile that C with MIPS C compiler... ....ok, I will tell you, as I can feel the tension: it will implement it in MIPS assembly.

Comment: @Ped7g The point is for me to actually write code (and hopefully learn something from that), not generate it from a tool, copy paste it and get an  artificial grade :/ But I'll have you know I wrote the code myself and it works ^_^ Thanks for the info though.

Comment: @AlexTsalikis sure, I appreciated you managed to do it and I hope you will enjoy the learning experience, I was just answering your (rhetorical?) question, whether it is possible. Obviously, if you can write it in C (or any other programming language supported by MIPS), it *must* be possible also in ASM. Whether it would be easy to do... with complex languages and examples very likely not. Actually writing it in C first (+debug and fix algorithm) may help with the assembly code logic and structure a lot.